# Yodlee Aggregation REST API register3 userPreferences Options

Tags: rest, aggregation, yodlee

I'm searching through the Aggregation API reference and I can't find a comprehensive list of the possible key-value pairs you can supply for the userPreferences parameter to [register3](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/register3).  My reading of the documentation is that the key and value are tilde-separated, but since none of the sample preferences identified in the Description match the sample key/value pairs in the Example column.  The actual user preferences must be documented somewhere, but where?

Or have I incorrectly assumed that these are user preferences that affect Yodlee functionality?  Is this just a generic dictionary Yodlee is providing into which I can insert and later retrieve values by any keys I make up, without having any other effect on Yodlee functionality?

Thanks

Comment: BUMP - i assume you would have to look at the java docs?

Comment: Oh, wow.  I didn't even know the java docs existed.  Those will be very helpful outside of this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the keys use what yodlee call "EXTENTED_USER_PROFILE_PREFIX".  I was unable to find a list of prefixes but the following key value pairs work.

```
"userPreferences[0]", "PREFERRED_CURRENCY~AUD"
"userPreferences[1]", "PREFERRED_DATE_FORMAT~dd/MM/yyyy"
"userPreferences[2]", "com.yodlee.userprofile.TIMEZONE~GMT"
```

If you need more information there might be some answers in the javadoc but keep in mind it is for the SOAP API.

> /com/yodlee/soap/core/usermanagement/userregistration/UserRegistration.html#register3

Answer (score 0):

OK i have looked through the Java docs and cant see anything helpful. The parameter is a NVP but the keys are not specified, and i cant find anything related that would provide a hint. Given the input keys also don't follow an obvious translation i feel this could be difficult to guess.
I would have thought that an exception would have been thrown for invalid keys, but it does not. 
To set the time zone i have tried:

```
"userPreferences[2]", "PREFERRED_TIME_ZONE~GMT"

"userPreferences[2]", "PREFERRED_TIMEZONE~GMT"

"userPreferences[2]", "TIMEZONE~GMT"
```

None adjust the returned prefered timezone. To be honest even if it did i doubt i would achieve what i am trying to achieve.

these settings did work however:

```
"userPreferences[0]", "PREFERRED_CURRENCY~AUD"
"userPreferences[1]", "PREFERRED_DATE_FORMAT~dd/MM/yyyy"
```